# Laravel migration deployment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, migration

Just a quick one really

I have an existing Laravel app

I want to use a migration to add some columns to an existing table

So i do the following:

```
php artisan make:migration add_columns_to_table
```

Which creates a file in my migrations folder called:

```
2017_10_25_124938_add_column_to_table.php
```

And also creates an entry in my migrations table in the database. All good.

I can edit the migration file (adding the columns etc) and run

```
php artisan migrate
```

And everything works great

Now - my question is this:

When i come to deploy to live i am presuming I would log onto the live box and run the create migration command again:

```
php artisan make:migration add_columns_to_table
```

But this will create a migration with a different name to the one i created / tested locally?

So - do i then need to manually copy the code from my local 2017_10_25_124938_add_column_to_table.php migration file to the one created on the live box?

That seems a bit backwards and fiddly

What is the best way of creating and testing a migration locally and then deploying it to live when the create migration command creates a different named migration file (and DB entry) on the live box?

Or have i got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: The purpose of migrations is to get DB design changes into version control. So yes, you deploy / upload the same file to your production server and then just run `php artisan migrate` there after that. Why would you create a new migration separately on the production server? Ar you doing different things there in development and in production?

Comment: But if i simply deploy the local file to live there won't be an entry in the live database for the migration will there? So how will laravel know to run it? Or does the artisan migrate command just run everything in the migration folder?

Comment: No, the pure presence of the migration file does not affect your DB :) Whe you run `php artisan migrate` for the first time, Laravel creates a `migrations` table in the DB where it keeps track of the migrations that have already been run. Then it scans all files in the migration folder, filters only the new ones (i.e. the ones are not in the `migrations` table), runs them and adds them to that table so they won't be run the next time you run `php artisan migrate`. (Not quite sure if I understood your question, if that's not what you wanted to know, ask away :) )

Comment: Aaah no gotcha. My bad, i thought it used the table to decide which migrations to run. But it actually uses it to know which NOT to run. Cheers. That clears it up. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to keep migration files with the repo. While deploying the application on any environment you have to execute all migrations.

```
php artisan migrate
```

This command will run all the migrations which are not already executed in the current environment. Laravel use a table called 'migrations' to keep track of all the migrations it has run.